# Convert an ostream into a string (not a sstream)

Tags: string, ostream, sstream

I specifically need to convert an ostream into a string. To be more precise, I have a function:

```
ostream& f(ostream& out);
```

(This function is mainly used for a polymorphic overcharge of the << operator)
In this case, I need to get what is in the ostream into the string. After some research, I tried this:

```
stringstream test;
ofstream tmp;
test << f(tmp);
string foo(test.str());
```

But the string only contains 0s.
Does anyone have a solution for this ?

Thank you

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "what is in the ostream" - an ostream is an abstraction of an output stream - do you mean what is in its buffer at a given point?.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `ostringstream` class instead of `ofstream`

```
ostringstream test;
test << f(test);
string foo(test.str());
```

Comment: Thank you very much that was quick and on point; There is a continuation question: how does the order work?

Comment: Which order? Do you mean order of statement executions?

Comment: I mean: if you write : test << string << f(test) or test << f(test) << string; it gives the same thing is that normal ?

Comment: this depends on what your function f(test) do. if it writes to stream, then it executes first, modifies the stream, and after that a string being copied to that stream. i suggest you can even write simply f(test)<<string in that cause. writing stream to itself does nothing here, because it is open in write-only mode.